# Problems with printer share on Windows7-64 with an Ubuntu-32

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, 64-bit, printer

For years I've had a WindowsXP-32 bits on which was installed a Canon MP210 printer. This printer was shared to be used by the Ubuntu of another computer. In CUPS, the url of the printer was "smb://192.168.0.2/canonMP" and it worked like a charm. As far as I can remember, that's the only thing I had to set to share the printer.

Just this weekend, I've upgraded my gear and replaced my WindowsXP-32 by Windows7-64 and I'm having troubles with printing from Ubuntu.

Since I'm a bit new with Windows7 and 64 bits systems, I'm not sure which direction to investigate. 64 bits drivers for Ubuntu? An other protocol than CIFS?
One sure thing is that the firewall of Windows7 isn't responsible: I tried printing a test with the firewall down and it didn't work. I also correctly set the share name of the printer.

Answer (score 1):

I would switch from "smb" to "[ipp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Printing_Protocol)" as the printer protocol. Regarding 64/32bit OS: does not matter, imho, because you exchange things via the network.

Comment: So the url set in CUPS should be ipp://192.168.0.2/ipp/, right ? I just tried that and still no answer from the printer.

Comment: can you ping the printer? is it a network printer? is your CUPS providing the print-queue? is your CUPS-machine pingable?

Comment: I can't ping the printer because it's a USB printer installed on the Seven. CUPS shows the print-queue, with the documents not being processed. The CUPS machine is pingable, as well as the printer-host.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved : the key was to install the lpd service on the seven and use it in CUPS.